# Injecting scoped activity with @ContributesAndroidInjector

Tags: java, android, dagger-2

I have a service that needs an instance of an Activity and wondering if it is possible to do this while using the @ContributesAndroidInjector annotation as described here: https://google.github.io/dagger//android.html. I want the Service to be scoped to the activity, and it has to be usable with multiple different activities.

```
public class MyService {
    @Inject
    public MyService(Activity activity) { }
}
```

The code for the activity module:

```
@ContributesAndroidInjector(modules = { MyActivityModule.class })
abstract YourActivity contributeYourActivityInjector();
```

I'm not sure how to set this up correctly, and have tried countless different variations, but mostly getting errors stating the "Activity" cannot be instantiated.

`MyActivityModule` provides `AndroidInjector` instances for the fragments used in the activity, and I've attempted to add a @Provides annotated method that takes in `YourActivity` and returns `MyService` but that doesn't work either.

Could someone point me in the right direction? Is it possible to do using @ContributesAndroidInjector ? If not, what do I need to do to provide the activity, and have the service scoped correctly? I can see how I could do that using vanilla Dagger2 and setting the activity in onCreate before injecting it,  but how do I do that when using `AndroidInjection.inject(this)`?

Comment: Activities are things users DO. The exception makes sense

Comment: I guess I would rephrase what @efekctive told: you are not the one, who creates an activity, the framework does it. But with that declaration you are trying to provide an `Activity` instance to the constructor of `Service`. Obviously, you haven't specified how this activity should be created, and dagger is non-wiser. What is your use case? Why do you need an activity to be injected in the constructor?

Comment: From a high level, it seems that the service is something that an activity would need

Comment: I need the activity or context to provide a service instance of Glide that is scoped to the activity lifecycle.